# What is SimpleActionServer and SimpleActionClient for ros2?

Tags: ros, ros2, simpleactionclient

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. Is there SimpleActionServer and SimpleActionClient implementation for ros2? I found nav2_util::SimpleActionServer, but it's not working for some reason right now on my system so I don't know if it works like actionlib::SimpleActionServer from ros1. I found nothing about SimpleActionClient for ros2. I'd appreciate any help, especially if you could give an example.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407744/what-is-simpleactionserver-and-simpleactionclient-for-ros2?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, no, there is no simple action server / client in ROS 2. You should use the Nav2 Utils one. There are discussions about adding it though, but TBD on that being released.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-12**:
I understand, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is [DLu/simple_actions](https://github.com/DLu/simple_actions):

> A simple version of the `rclpy`/`rclcpp` action libraries.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-10-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-13**:
Thank you, I'll check